# log4j isn't logging while runnings junit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, log4j

I have a Java+Maven web project running on Tomcat8, with JUnit.
Log4j configuration file is inside `src/main/resources/` and is printing log when I run the application, however when I run JUnit tests log4j isn't printing anything except errors because it can't find the config file.

The tests are located in `src/test/resources/` and there's an l4j.properties file in there too. How do I configure my pom.xml file to accept both?

my pom is has:

```
<properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <log4j.configuration>src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
</properties>
```

Comment: what do you mean in making a common logging scope ?

Comment: here's my pom.xml http://pastebin.com/qsxEGhZk

Comment: aaa... sorry2 my mistake, I thought you're referring to a log4j that cannot print out the message information when trying to run the unit test. for the properties file. is it possible if you create a new profile so that the profile will take the properties file in test folder instead of using the main one?

Comment: maybe, can i use these different profiles when i run and when i test my application using netbeans ?

Comment: I haven't use netbeans since quite a long time, so I don't know that. maybe you could because you sure can do that with eclipse and idea .